# In Android, how can I get 7 Fragments with the same parent Activity to communicate onClicks?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have one parent Activity. That Activity holds seven instances of the same Fragment. In each fragment is 7 buttons (days of the week), and you'd select any combination of days for each fragment, but only one day can be selected out of the seven fragments. What I need is for when one fragment's button is clicked (let's say Monday), each Monday button in each of the other fragment's to grey out (I'll set to not enabled and change color). Likewise, when you deselect Monday, all the other Mondays will be re-enabled.

I'm reading Android's recommendation for inter-fragment communication here:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface

But I can't quite wrap my head around how it'll work exactly in my case

Any help's appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use your activity to communicate to all your fragments.

Keep a reference to all your 7 fragment in your activity, then from within a fragment ask your activity to notify to all your fragment new data has to be showed.

Then in your fragments' methods update your view accordingly.

To ask your activity to do some stuff from within your fragment you can use the events way. There are many libraries as [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) to achieve this goal